# RabbitMq plugin for grails throwing UnknownHostException

Tags: grails, rabbitmq, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-plugin-rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitmq 0.3.3 plugin with grails 2.0. I have created one queue no exchanges and when I try to call this queue I get following exception.

```
Class:   java.net.UnknownHostException
Message: placeholder
```

```
22:            // it does for the other arguments. Since the code in that method
23:            // checks for String, we do the conversion manually.
24:            args = processArgs(args)
25:            ctx.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(*args)
26:        }
27:    }
28:
```

```
rabbitSend 'mailQueue', [personId:person.id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server where you are running this code is not able to resolve the host name and i would advise you to add the host name in your host.conf file on system with IPaddress. or try with the IP address.

Hope it helps.
Kulveer Singh

Comment: Its on my local machine and I have another grails 1.3.4 project with same configurations which is working fine.